# How ISubject and Subject will look like in this sample and are the sample using them in the right place?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-4.0, eventaggregator

I got this sample http://jfromaniello.blogspot.com/2010/04/event-aggregator-with-reactive.html,

Which describe event aggregator pattern using .net 4.0 but i didn't find in the sample code the ISubject interface and the Subject class and i found the he is using them in the EventAggregator class, is it right to use them like that and what will their code will look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking here - are you just looking for the ISubject interface and implementation? If so you can grab them (along with all the System.Reactive bits) from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

Use the download links on the right for whatever platform(s) you are using.

Comment: so they both exist in the System.Reactive?