# Set Selectedindex of combobox in Window1 from Window2 in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have two windows(forms). In the first window I have a combobox, in the second window I have a button. How do I set the selectedindex of the combobox in windows 1 when the button in window 2 is clicked?

I have tried this without success:

in Window1:

```
public int OutputCombostr
    {
        get { return this.OutputCombo.SelectedIndex; }
        set { this.OutputCombo.SelectedIndex = value; }
    }
```

In Window2:

```
  private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                MainWindow firstwindow = new MainWindow();

                firstwindow.OutputCombostr = 3;
            }
```

Comment: you don't happen to be using MVVM (Model View ViewModel). This would be so much easier if you are, but I'm figuring you are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MVVM would be very useful to you, but also you may obtain a reference to the main window using this code: `Application.Current.MainWindow` or for getting all applictaion's windows: `Application.Current.Windows`.

For access to the combobox you need first give it a name in the xaml code: `<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox">...` And then, from the second window make a cast `(Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).comboBox.IsChecked` supposing that your main window's class is name `MainWindow`. Also i think it is better to use the MVVM pattern to solve this.

Hope this could helps to you...

Comment: How do I access the combobox?

Comment: The Application.Current.MainWindow is a Window object, you need to cast it. Please see my answer update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to some how get a reference to the existing instance of your `MainWindow` class.  If this is WPF and that window is indeed your start up object, then you should be able to access it via `Application.MainWindow` (rather than newing it up).

Alternatively, you might look into something like the event aggregator pattern.  Here's a SO question that you could use as a starting point: [Trying to understand the event aggregator pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436853/trying-to-understand-the-event-aggregator-pattern)

Comment: I can't access it using Application.MainWindow.

Comment: Because this isn't your start up window?  Or something else?